# mapping multiple values to get single value

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

$0.8,0.9,0.7,0.4,0.2,0.1 \Rightarrow x$

I want to map all values to $x$, such that $x$ can represent all values.
One way I can think of is mean. But, it won't be useful if variance is high.

eg. $0.9,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.1,0.1,0.2 = mean$ is $0.52$

So, it doesn't represent all values in a bin.

is there any other way to get $x$?

Comment: What is your domain and range? It seems like you want something along the lines of 

$f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

where $f$ maps a set of real numbers to some value such that $f^{-1}$ exists AND is unique. Please be more specific with your question.

Comment: possibly using the median instead?

Comment: let numbers x in the range [a,b] and you want to transform them to numbers y in the range [c,d] you need to do this: I don't have specific range.otherwise, I could have used  y=(x−a)((d−c)/b−a)+c

Comment: Median won't work because if I have 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1. here 0.9 doesn't make any sense

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "so that $x$ can represent all values"? Also why do you insist on having one mapping? If you could map data to one universally informative number, don't you think the breadth of statistics literature would be considerably smaller? You should consider using multiple statistics calculated from the data if you want to get better "representations" of the data.

Comment: Can you suggest some methods?